# Remove separator in Flex List after dropping

Tags: apache-flex

When I drag elements from one Spark List to another Spark List, in my List in which drop occured I keep drag separator between rows. How can I remove this separator after dropping please ?

Comment: A screenshot may help here.  Also some code. I'm unclear if this is an issue with your code or an issue with the List class.

Comment: Ok I have understood why I have this behaviour. I use event.stopImmediatePropagation() on DragEvent.DRAG_DROP on my List and handle via custom vector values to drop in my List to prevent duplicates. This is why I have this separator but I don't know why

Comment: If Ihad to guess; your stopImmedaiitePropagation() call prevents a handler from running in the list class.  What if you try stopPropagation() instead of stopImmediatePropogation()?  [I'm not sure that will make a difference].  I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this w/o stopping the event; but I Don't have time to read up on all the drag/drop related events right now.

Comment: This is the same result with stopPropagation(). I'm refactoring my code to keep the "logical" process of drag and drop and I will remove duplicates after with ArrayCollection.filter() function.

Comment: During the drag; you should be able to do something to show the 'X' icon which means the drag is not allowable.  Much better UI than removing it after the fact.  Google for "Flex prevent dropping certain items".  This seems to be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544232/how-to-prevent-an-item-being-dropped-into-one-tilelist-from-another-using-flex

Comment: I have a complex use-case because I have one list in which I have all values to make drag and drop and many other lists where I can drop in it. But when I'm dropping, I want my first list to keep all original values and I want to avoid duplicates on another lists (all worked but the separator between rows didn't deseapper). I think with a filter fonction on my ArrayColletion it will work now. Thanks for the link.